# What's wrong with my ContentProvider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I am trying to create my own content provider for the first time and am having trouble figuring out what I have done wrong. When I run the test code at the bottom, I am getting an unknown URI exception and, for the life of me, I can't figure out what's wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

CodesContentProvider.java

```
public class CodesContentProvider extends ContentProvider {

private static final String TAG = "CodesContentProvider";

private static String DATABASE_NAME;

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private static final String CODES_TABLE_NAME = "codes";

private static final String TITLES_TABLE_NAME = "titles";

public static final String AUTHORITY = "com.xxx.capenal.providers.CodesContentProvider";

private static UriMatcher sUriMatcher;

private static final int CODES = 1;

private static final int TITLES = 2;

private static SQLiteDatabase mDatabase = null;

private static HashMap<String, String> codesProjectionMap;

private static HashMap<String, String> titlesProjectionMap;




private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

        File path; 
        final File DataDirectory;
        path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        DataDirectory = new File(path,context.getString(R.string.DATABASE_DIRECTORY));
        DATABASE_NAME = new File(DataDirectory, context.getString(R.string.DATABASE_FILE_NAME)).toString();


    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //TODO: Add titles to this statement
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + CODES_TABLE_NAME + " (" + Codes.CODE_ID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + Codes.PARENT_ID + " VARCHAR(255)," + Codes.CODE
                + " LONGTEXT" + ");");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion
                + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + CODES_TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized SQLiteDatabase getReadableDatabase() {

        try {
            return getWritableDatabase();
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
                //Log.e("", "Couldn't open " + DATABASE_NAME + " for writing (will try read-only):", e);
        }

        SQLiteDatabase db = null;

        try {
            //mIsInitializing = true;
            db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
            if (db.getVersion() != DATABASE_VERSION) {
                throw new SQLiteException("Can't upgrade read-only database from version " + db.getVersion() + " to "
                    + DATABASE_VERSION + ": " + DATABASE_NAME);
        }
            onOpen(db);
            mDatabase = db;
            return mDatabase;
        } finally {
            //mIsInitializing = false;
            if (db != null && db != mDatabase)
                db.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized SQLiteDatabase getWritableDatabase() {
        boolean success = false;
        SQLiteDatabase db = null;
        // if (mDatabase != null) mDatabase.lock(); //can't call the locks for
        // some reason. beginTransaction does lock it though
        try {
            //mIsInitializing = true;
            db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, null);
            int version = db.getVersion();
            if (version != DATABASE_VERSION) {
                db.beginTransaction();
                try {
                    if (version == 0) {
                            onCreate(db);
                    } else {
                            onUpgrade(db, version, DATABASE_VERSION);
                    }
                    db.setVersion(DATABASE_VERSION);
                    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
                } finally {
                    db.endTransaction();
                }
            }
            onOpen(db);
            success = true;
            return db;
        } finally {
             // mIsInitializing = false;
             if (success) {
                 if (mDatabase != null) {
                     try {
                         mDatabase.close();
                     } catch (Exception e) {
                     }
                     // mDatabase.unlock();
                 }
                 mDatabase = db;
             } else {
                 // if (mDatabase != null) mDatabase.unlock();
                 if (db != null)
                     db.close();
             }
         }
     }
}

private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;

@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String where, String[] whereArgs) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    int count;
    switch (sUriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case CODES:
            count = db.delete(CODES_TABLE_NAME, where, whereArgs);
            break;

        case TITLES:
            count = db.delete(TITLES_TABLE_NAME, where, whereArgs);
            break;

        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri);
    }

    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    return count;
}

@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
    switch (sUriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case CODES:
            return Codes.CONTENT_TYPE;

        case TITLES:
            return Titles.CONTENT_TYPE;

        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri);
    }
}

@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues initialValues) {
    if (sUriMatcher.match(uri) != CODES) { throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri); }

    ContentValues values;
    if (initialValues != null) {
        values = new ContentValues(initialValues);
    } else {
        values = new ContentValues();
    }

    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    long rowId = db.insert(CODES_TABLE_NAME, Codes.DEFINITION, values);
    if (rowId > 0) {
        Uri CodeUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Codes.CONTENT_URI, rowId);
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(CodeUri, null);
        return CodeUri;
    }

    throw new SQLException("Failed to insert row into " + uri);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());
    return true;
}

@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

    switch (sUriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case CODES:
            qb.setTables(CODES_TABLE_NAME);
            qb.setProjectionMap(codesProjectionMap);
            break;

        case TITLES:
            qb.setTables(TITLES_TABLE_NAME);
            qb.setProjectionMap(titlesProjectionMap);
            break;

        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri);
    }

    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = qb.query(db, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);

    c.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
    return c;
}

@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String where, String[] whereArgs) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    int count;
    switch (sUriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case CODES:
            count = db.update(CODES_TABLE_NAME, values, where, whereArgs);
            break;

        case TITLES:
            count = db.update(TITLES_TABLE_NAME, values, where, whereArgs);
            break;

        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri);
    }

    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    return count;
}

static {
    sUriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    sUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, CODES_TABLE_NAME, CODES);

    codesProjectionMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    codesProjectionMap.put(Codes.CODE_ID, Codes.CODE_ID);
    codesProjectionMap.put(Codes.PARENT_ID, Codes.PARENT_ID);
    codesProjectionMap.put(Codes.CODE, Codes.CODE);
    codesProjectionMap.put(Codes.DEFINITION, Codes.DEFINITION);
    codesProjectionMap.put(Codes.EXCERPT, Codes.EXCERPT);

}

static {
    sUriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    sUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, TITLES_TABLE_NAME, TITLES);

    titlesProjectionMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    titlesProjectionMap.put(Titles.TYPE, Titles.TYPE);
    titlesProjectionMap.put(Titles.SECTION, Titles.SECTION);
    titlesProjectionMap.put(Titles.FULL_TITLE, Titles.FULL_TITLE);
    titlesProjectionMap.put(Titles.TITLE, Titles.TITLE);
    titlesProjectionMap.put(Titles.TITLE_ID, Titles.TITLE_ID);
    titlesProjectionMap.put(Titles.PARENT_ID, Titles.PARENT_ID);
    titlesProjectionMap.put(Titles.CODE_RANGE, Titles.CODE_RANGE);

}
```

}

```
public class Code {

public Code() {
}

public static final class Codes implements BaseColumns {
    private Codes() {
    }

    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://"
            + CodesContentProvider.AUTHORITY + "/codes");

    public static final String CONTENT_TYPE = "vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.xxx.codes";

    public static final String CODE_ID = "_id";
    public static final String PARENT_ID = "parent_id";
    public static final String CODE = "code";
    public static final String DEFINITION = "definition";
    public static final String EXCERPT = "excerpt";
}
```

}

```
      <provider android:name="com.xxx.capenal.providers.CodesContentProvider" 
    android:authorities="com.xxx.capenal.providers.CodesContentProvider" />
```

Test Code:

```
// Form an array specifying which columns to return. 
    String[] projection = new String[] {
                                 Codes._ID,
                                 Codes.CODE_ID,
                                 Codes.PARENT_ID,
                                 Codes.EXCERPT
                              };

    // Get the base URI for the People table in the Contacts content provider.
    Uri codes =  Codes.CONTENT_URI;

    // Make the query. 
    Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(codes,
                             projection, // Which columns to return 
                             null,       // Which rows to return (all rows)
                             null,       // Selection arguments (none)
                             // Put the results in ascending order by name
                             Codes.CODE_ID + " ASC");
```

Stack Trace:

```
05-17 17:49:48.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22769): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-17 17:49:48.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22769): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.xxx.capenal/com.xxx.capenal.main}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.xxx.capenal/com.xxx.capenal.parent}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URI content://com.xxx.capenal.providers.CodesContentProvider/codes/23
05-17 17:49:48.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22769):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2487)
05-17 17:49:48.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22769):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2444)
05-17 17:49:48.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22769):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2422)
05-17 17:49:48.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22769):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:122)
05-17 17:49:48.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22769):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1009)
05-17 17:49:48.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22769):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-17 17:49:48.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22769):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
05-17 17:49:48.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22769):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
05-17 17:49:48.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22769):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-17 17:49:48.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22769):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
05-17 17:49:48.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22769):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
05-17 17:49:48.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22769):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
05-17 17:49:48.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22769):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-17 17:49:48.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22769): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.xxx.capenal/com.xxx.capenal.parent}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URI content://com.xxx.capenal.providers.CodesContentProvider/codes/23
05-17 17:49:48.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22769):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2487)
05-17 17:49:48.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22769):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2444)
05-17 17:49:48.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22769):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.performPause(LocalActivityManager.java:203)
05-17 17:49:48.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22769):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:187)
05-17 17:49:48.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22769):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.dispatchPause(LocalActivityManager.java:547)
05-17 17:49:48.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22769):     at android.app.ActivityGroup.onPause(ActivityGroup.java:73)
05-17 17:49:48.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22769):     at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:4452)
05-17 17:49:48.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22769):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1194)
05-17 17:49:48.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22769):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2474)
05-17 17:49:48.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22769):     ... 12 more
05-17 17:49:48.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22769): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URI content://com.xxx.capenal.providers.CodesContentProvider/codes/23
05-17 17:49:48.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22769):     at com.xxx.capenal.providers.CodesContentProvider.query(CodesContentProvider.java:241)
05-17 17:49:48.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22769):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:192)
05-17 17:49:48.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22769):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:302)
05-17 17:49:48.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22769):     at android.app.Activity.managedQuery(Activity.java:1670)
05-17 17:49:48.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22769):     at com.xxx.capenal.parent.onPause(parent.java:160)
05-17 17:49:48.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22769):     at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:4452)
05-17 17:49:48.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22769):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1194)
05-17 17:49:48.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22769):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.jav
```

a:2474)
05-17 17:49:48.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22769):     ... 20 more

Comment: To me, it seems that you're assigning twice to `sUriMatcher` in the two static initializer blocks at the end of the `CodesContentProvider` class.

Comment: You were absolutely correct. I don't know how I thought that would have worked. Would you mind making this an answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're assigning twice to `sUriMatcher` in the two static initializer blocks at the end of the `CodesContentProvider` class.